# seq results compare with vector return false

Tags: r, vector, logic

I have the following code:

```
     seq(0.2, 0.4, by = 0.1) == c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4)
```

which yields:

```
     [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Could somebody please explain this result?

Comment: You should read the R-FAQ.This is in section 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is numerical error:

```
> seq(0.2, 0.4, by = 0.1)-c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4)
[1] 0.000000e+00 5.551115e-17 0.000000e+00
```

See `?identical` or `?all.equal` and compare:

```
> identical(seq(0.2, 0.4, by = 0.1),c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4))
[1] FALSE
> all.equal(seq(0.2, 0.4, by = 0.1),c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4))
[1] TRUE
```

Also compare:

```
> seq(2L,4L,by=1L)/10==c(.2,.3,.4)
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```